How come neither Venom nor Riot were affected at the end of the movie?
In Venom (2018), we learn that the symbiotes are vulnerable to both fire and some sound frequencies. There are a few scenes during which the sound vulnerability is depicted:

Near the beginning of the movie when the alarms blare after Eddie attempted to input a wrong combination to free Maria.
When Eddie's neighbour is playing his electric guitar very loudly, which annoys him.
At the top of a building when Venom was enjoying the view, before a plane flew by and made them (Venom and Eddie) fall down.
When fighting the police, as they threw what seemed to be stun/concussion grenades.
Also in a deleted scene when a car alarm starts ringing.
And near the end of the movie when Eddie's ex is playing with the volume knob of the speakers.

However, at the climax of the movie, when the rocket is launched, neither Venom nor Riot (who's inside the rocket) seem to be affected by the noise whatsoever, even though a rocket is probably several times louder than a plane.

I would have added a video for each of the examples, but that would have been too many videos.

Interestingly enough, in Spiderman TAS, in the episode in which the symbiote appears, it did end up with a rocket flying away, and the loud noise did detach Venom from whomever it was attached to.
